# How to use Acra reportDialogClass

Tags: android, acra

I asked a question about allowing a user to add a custom comment upon a crash [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663330/add-user-input-to-acra-crash-report) and got the tip that ACRA 4.6 included a mechanism for just that. I couldn't find any documentation or examples on how to use this, so I tried to figure it out myself, but I haven't succeeded in getting the behavior I want. I tried, for instance, adding this to the annotation:

```
reportDialogClass = CustomReportDialog.class
```

and this is what I wrote just to see if I could get a dialog to show:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.acra.BaseCrashReportDialog;

public class CustomReportDialog extends BaseCrashReportDialog {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setMessage("yo").setPositiveButton("pos", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).create().show();
    }
}
```

In general, BaseCrashReportDialog.class seems kind of confusing to me because I would have expected it to provide some kind of framework for a dialog to pop up, but it just extends from Activity, hence why I tried to show my own AlertDialog. Has anyone figured out how to properly implement this new feature? Thanks

EDIT Per William's request:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        formUri = BuildConfig.SERVER_DOMAIN,
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text,
        disableSSLCertValidation = true,
        additionalSharedPreferences = {BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID},
        excludeMatchingSharedPreferencesKeys = {CommonUtils.PROPERTY_REG_ID, CommonUtils.PREFS_SESSION_TOKEN},
        reportDialogClass = CustomReportDialog.class
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the comment in BaseCrashReportDialog that says "[sub classes] must call super.onCreate() at the beginning of the method.". You need to do that.

You should also do something in your `onClick` such as call `BaseCrashReportDialog.sendCrash()`

Have a look at [CrashReportDialog.java](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/CrashReportDialog.java) for a starting point.

You also need to configure `mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG`

Comment: Hey William, thanks for this. I tried lots of ways to try and implement this and even went so far as to completely copy and paste the contents of CrashReportDialog.java into my own custom class. I added launchMode="singleInstance" to my manifest according to the comment at the top. Bottom line is that nothing works. Have you yourself successfully implemented this and had a dialog show upon a crash? Am I missing something critical to make this work?

Comment: Yes I have successfully implemented it within my own pap. As has the person who submitted it. If you have copied CrashReportDialog and it is not working then there is something wrong with your config. When you say "it is not working" what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure I'm doing something wrong and I really want to figure it out :). So what I mean is that my expected behavior is that when the app crashes a dialog pops up before the crash is sent. What's actually happening when I try this is that a crash is sent and no dialog is ever shown. Am I configuring my acra annotation correctly? Any other ideas of what it might be?

Comment: Show your entire ACRA config

Comment: Solution is to configure `mode=DIALOG` - see amended answer.